# How to use icon in routes using Durandal?

Tags: durandal

I was looking around the documentation of the structures of these route-info object, but I didn't find any. Since Durandal use other JS libs, I don't sure what is this belong to (maybe sammy?).

I am facing 2 problems:
**Problem #1** I want to use an icon in the route information, and I found that I could use title or caption to accomplish that... 
Ugly Option 1: using icon info in the caption

```
{ route: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', moduleId: 'viewmodels/dashboard', nav: true, caption: 'icon-dashboard' },
```

and do some binding like this:

```
<i data-bind="attr: { 'class': caption}"></i>
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
```

or Ugly Option2: using icon html code in the model

```
{ route: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', moduleId: 'viewmodels/dashboard', nav: true, caption: '<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Dashboard' }
```

and the binding will be:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: caption"></a>
```

I personally like option 1, because the is separation of data and display. But the property (caption) is not the best place to put it... what other options are??? I saw people using setting, but again, what settings-options are?? can I create my own icon property?

**Other Problem** How to design sub-menu... if is there a property to reference a parent-route??

**Update 8/23/2013** I found this info about [Child Routers](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/)

Comment: In durandal 2.0 (which it looks like you are using) the router is no longer SammyJs. It is a Durandal plugin, "in-house" if you will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your own properties to the `route` object. This is the good thing about JavaScript!

So as you say, you could add a settings object to the route like this:

```
{ route: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', moduleId: 'viewmodels/dashboard', nav: true, settings : { caption: 'icon-dashboard', another :'property'} }
```

And just do the binding the same way you were doing:

```
<i data-bind="attr: { 'class': settings.caption}"></i>
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
```

Just make sure that all your objects that will be bound in the UI contain the `settings.caption`or add extra logic in the binding to manage route objects that which property is`undefined`.

Comment: I tried that but I guess some of the values were undefined... now it's working fine. I added `settings.iconClass`